# How to get list of objects with unique attribute

Tags: python, list, set

### Background

I have a `list`. 
This `list` has many objects. Each object has an `id`. Now the objects are of different types.

```
objects = [Aobject, Bobject, Cobject]
```

where

```
>>> Aobject != Bobject
True
>>> Aobject.id ==  Bobject.id
True
```

### Problem

I want a `list` of unique objects based on the `object.id`.

Something like this:

```
set(objects, key=operator.attrgetter('id'))
```

(This does not work. But I want something like this)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use a `set`:

```py
seen = set()
uniqueidlist = []
for obj in mylist:
    if obj.id not in seen:
        seen.add(obj.id)
        uniqueidlist.append(obj)
```

Or equivalently:

```py
seen = set()
uniqueidlist = [seen.add(obj.id) or obj for obj in mylist if obj.id not in seen]
```

This works because `set.add` returns `None`, so the expression in the list comprehension always yields `obj`, but only if `obj.id` has not already been added to `seen`.

The expression could only evaluate to `None` if `obj is None`; in that case, `obj.id` would raise an exception. In case `mylist` contains `None` values, change the test to `if obj and (obj.id not in seen)`.

Note that for each `obj.id`, this will keep the first `obj` in the list which has that `obj.id`.

**Update**

Alternatively, you can use a `dict`:

```py
seen = {}
for obj in mylist:
    if obj.id not in seen:
        seen[obj.id] = obj
uniqueidlist = list(seen.values())
```

Note that for each `obj.id`, this will keep the first `obj` in the list which has that `obj.id`. Remove the test if you want to keep the last such `obj`, or use [@Abhijit’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025086/2326961).

Comment: I like this idea although i'm not sure if the use of `or` is considered good practise in this case.

Comment: Not sure, if you think it is good practice then i will take your word for it :D

Comment: @Marcin feels a bit fishy because relies on the fact that (None or obj) evaluates to obj, which is a special case for or and somewhat arbitrarily defined 

Nice idea nevertheless!

Answer (score 8):

How about using `dict` (since its keys are unique)?

Assuming we have

```py
class Object:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id


Aobject = Object(1)
Bobject = Object(1)
Cobject = Object(2)
objects = [Aobject, Bobject, Cobject]
```

then `list` with `Object`s unique by `id` field can be generated using `dict` comprehension in **Python 3**

```py
unique_objects = list({object_.id: object_ for object_ in objects}.values())
```

in **Python 2.7**

```py
unique_objects = {object_.id: object_ for object_ in objects}.values()
```

and in **Python <2.7**

```py
unique_objects = dict([(object_.id, object_) for object_ in objects]).values()
```

Finally, we can write a function (**Python3**, which also preserves insertion order)

```py
import sys
from typing import Callable, Hashable, List, Optional, Sequence, TypeVar

if sys.version_info < (3, 6):
    from collections import OrderedDict as _OrderedDict
else:
    # starting from Python3.6 `dict`s are insertion ordered by default
    _OrderedDict = dict

_T = TypeVar('_T')


def unique(values: Sequence[_T],
           key: Optional[Callable[[_T], Hashable]] = None) -> List[_T]:
    """
    Returns unique values by given key (using value itself by default)
    preserving order (taking first-from-start occurrence).

    Time complexity: O(len(values))
    Memory complexity: O(len(values

    >>> unique([-1, 1, 0, 1])
    [-1, 1, 0]
    >>> unique([-1, 1, 0, 1], key=abs)
    [-1, 0]
    """
    return list(
            _OrderedDict.fromkeys(values)
            if key is None
            else _OrderedDict((key(value), value)
                              for value in reversed(values)).values()
    )
```

where `values` may be any [`sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) (if you have an [`iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) -- you can just build a `list` from it before passing) and `key` is some `callable` which returns `hashable` objects from each of `values` (`key` equals to [`operator.attrgetter('id')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) in our particular case).

[Marcin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024750/5997596) works fine but doesn't look Pythonic to me since list comprehension mutates `seen` object from outer scope, also there is some magic behind using `set.add` method and comparing its result (which is `None`) with `obj`.

And final but not less important part:

## Benchmark

```py
import timeit

setup = '''
import random


class Object:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id


objects = [Object(random.randint(-100, 100))
           for i in range(1000)]
'''
solution = '''
seen = set()
result = [seen.add(object_.id) or object_
          for object_ in objects
          if object_.id not in seen]
'''
print('list comprehension + set: ',
      min(timeit.Timer(solution, setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
solution = '''
result = list({object_.id: object_
               for object_ in objects}.values())
'''
print('dict comprehension: ',
      min(timeit.Timer(solution, setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
```

on my Linux machine with **Python3.8** gives

```
list comprehension + set:  0.01755444100126624
dict comprehension:  0.012887613993370906
```

Comment: Your criticism is well taken. Consider however, that your solution could be simplified by using an ordereddict

Comment: Can you show an example how to use the `unique` function?

Comment: @QianChen: thanks, I've updated `unique` function: added docstrings & type annotations, also made `key` parameter optional

Answer (score 5):

Given your list of object `somelist` be something like

```
[(Object [A] [1]), (Object [B] [1]), (Object [C] [2]), (Object [D] [2]), (Object [E] [3])]
```

You can do something like this

```
>>> {e.id:e for e in somelist}.values()
[(Object [B] [1]), (Object [D] [2]), (Object [E] [3])]
```

Comment: This is cool. Note that it will give the last object with a given ID.

Comment: @Marcin: I agree but I believe OP never mentioned about which element he wants

Comment: Quite. It's not a criticism, just a note about its behaviour.

Comment: This is more readable than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
objects = [Aobject, Bobject, Cobject]
unique_objects = {o['id']:o for o in objects}.values()
```

Comment: You should add some info about this answer

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the class of the objects, you can add the appropriate methods which are used in set comparison:

```
# Assumption: this is the 'original' object
class OriginalExampleObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name, nid):
        self.name = name
        self.id = nid
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(OriginalExampleObject [%s] [%s])" % (self.name, self.id)

class SetExampleObj(OriginalExampleObject):
    def __init__(self, name, nid):
        super(SetExampleObj, self).__init__(name, nid)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.id.__hash__()


AObject = SetExampleObj("A", 1)
BObject = SetExampleObj("B", 1)
CObject = SetExampleObj("C", 2)

s = set()
s.add(AObject)
s.add(CObject)
print(s)

s.add(BObject)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
set([(OriginalExampleObject [A] [1]), (OriginalExampleObject [C] [2])])
set([(OriginalExampleObject [A] [1]), (OriginalExampleObject [C] [2])])
```

Comment: You don't need to do `self.id.__hash__()`. You can just do `return id(self)` as it returns an integer which is already a hashable object.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath It's a terrible choice, because it is almost exactly the same as `object`, which is a builtin. If you don't care about readers of your code, go ahead.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath The need for a new-style class is that this code may be copied by the inexperienced. Don't spread bad techniques.

Comment: @JoelCornett: No - it is not possible to use `return id(self)` here.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath: How so? I just did it. Do you mean that `self.id != id(self)`?

Comment: @Marcin: (a) I care :-) : therefore renamed. (b)+(c): also adapted your proposal.

Comment: @JoelCornett: If you replace `self.id.__hash__()` with `return id(self)` you get the wrong result: then both objects 'A' and 'B' are in the set.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath Awesome. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath : That's because they are separate instances. I assumed that OP wanted to know when two variables were referencing the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unique_everseen` recipe available in the `itertools` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). This is also available in 3rd party libraries, e.g. [`toolz.unique`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique). Note this method will keep the *first* instance of an object for a given attribute.

```
from toolz import unique
from operator import attrgetter

res = list(unique(objects, key=attrgetter('id')))
```

If a lazy iterator is sufficient, you can omit `list` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> l = [{'id': 1, 'x': 'foo'}, {'id': 1, 'x': 'bar'}, {'id': 2, 'x': 'baz'}]
>>> s = set()
>>> list(filter(lambda e: False if e['id'] in s else s.add(e['id']) or True, l))
[{'id': 1, 'x': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'x': 'baz'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

A fairly simple way to do this would be

```
for obj in mylist:
    if obj.id not in s:
        s.add(obj.id)
```

And this should add any id not seen. Time taken is linear on the size of the source list.

Comment: How does he get a set of the objects in `mylist`?