# List of objects with a unique attribute

Tags: python

I have a list of objects that each have a specific attribute.  That attribute is not unique, and I would like to end up with a list of the objects that is a subset of the entire list such that all of the specific attributes is a unique set.

For example, if I have four objects:

```
object1.thing = 1
object2.thing = 2
object3.thing = 3
object4.thing = 2
```

I would want to end up with either

```
[object1, object2, object3]
```

or

```
[object1, object3, object4]
```

The exact objects that wind up in the final list are not important, only that a list of their specific attribute is unique.

EDIT: To clarify, essentially what I want is a set that is keyed off of that specific attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique list using a key word :Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024646/how-to-get-unique-list-using-a-key-word-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could create a dict whose key is the object's thing and values are the objects themselves.

```
d = {}
for obj in object_list:
    d[obj.thing] = obj
desired_list = d.values()
```

Comment: Shorter: `dict((obj.thing, obj) for obj in object_list).values()`.

Comment: I definitely like that but I always have a hard time reading dict comprehensions, and I wanted to make it clear what I was doing.

Comment: Python 3 makes it prettier: `{obj.thing: obj for obj in object_list}` (but returns a view, not a list, from `values`).

Comment: Downvoted. This is a common practice, however, I believe using dicts this way is bad practice. This is the exact kind of use-case that sets were built for and they should be used instead.

Comment: Using dict comprehension: `{ obj.thing : obj for obj in object_list}.values()`. I find this slightly more readable that the most votes comment above.

Comment: Found that this approach was significantly (2000x in my case) faster for very large lists of objects compared to using the list approach from Ashwini.

Answer (score 28):

You can use a `list comprehension` and `set`:

```
objects = (object1,object2,object3,object4)
seen = set()
unique = [obj for obj in objects if obj.thing not in seen and not seen.add(obj.thing)]
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
seen = set()
unique = []
for obj in objects:
    if obj.thing not in seen:
        unique.append(obj)
        seen.add(obj.thing)
```

Comment: Upvoted because sets convey the task better than dicts do. Both use Python's notion of "hashable" object and thus are functionally equivalent. But if I'm reading your code, sets tells me "he wants a unique list of things" right away whereas dict tells me "he needs to map data", which in this case is misleading.

Comment: This is a nicer solution, but the code results in a syntax error in both Python 2 and 3.

unique = [obj for obj in objects if obj.thing not in seen and not seen.add(obj.thing)] 

is the right syntax