# Python: How to remove duplicate values(case insensitive) from a list with same order with default key 'ID' and other keys in title-case

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example:

'L' is a List.

L = ['id', 'Name', 'name', 'Name']

Result: ['ID', Name]

L = ['Name', 'name', 'Status']

Result: ['ID', 'Name', 'Status']

I have tried following code but I want more optmized solution, may be with list comprehension.

field_titles = ['id', 'Name', 'name', 'Name']

# Remove duplicate fields

```
    key_list = ['ID']
    for field in field_titles:

        title_field = field.title().strip()

        if not title_field == 'Id' and title_field not in key_list:

            key_list.append(title_field)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What do you mean keys?

Comment: You want to remove duplicates and then capitalize the first letter of every key? Show us what you have tried `L` in your example is a list and not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def transform(L):
    S = set(['id'])
    return ['ID'] + [
            item.title()
            for item in L
            if item.lower() not in S and not S.add(item.lower())]

assert transform(['id', 'Name', 'name', 'Name']) == ['ID', 'Name']
assert transform(['Name', 'name', 'Status']) == ['ID', 'Name', 'Status']
```

Comment: It might not be clear from the question, but I think the values should be capitalized.

Comment: @EricDuminil - Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rob,  Just a little change but your answer looks good to me.          Please see below:                                                                                                                                                                        <code> **>>>  S = set(['id']         **                                                                                             **>>>  ['ID'] + [item.title() for item in L if item.lower().strip() not in S and not S.add(item.lower().strip())]** <code>

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code, so I won't either.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347743/6419007) will help you, replacing `d[obj.thing] = obj` with `d[obj.lower()] = obj`. Since you want to keep the order, you'll need an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

At the end, you could check if `id` is in your keys. If it is, replace the value with `'ID'`. Replace all the other values with `value.capitalize()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def doIt(keyList):
    keyDict = {'id':'ID'}

    for word in keyList:
        wordLower = word.lower()
        if wordLower not in keyDict:
            keyDict[wordLower] = word.title()

    return keyDict.values()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = ['id', 'Name', 'name', 'Name']
    l2 = ['Name', 'name', 'Status']
    print toSet(l1), toSet(l2)
```

Comment: note that by using a `dict`, the input and output may be ordered different

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set() function:

```
list = ['name', 'Name', 'name', 'hi there']
list = set(list)
```

This will remove duplicates and return something like:

```
(['hi there', 'name', 'Name'])
```

Then you can convert back to a list:

```
list(list)  # the list() call constructs a new list with the values from the previously created set
```

Comment: The order of values should be maintened.