# Max index of repeating elements divisible by 'n' in a List in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a sorted list of numbers like:

```
a = [77,98,99,100,101,102,198,199,200,200,278,299,300,300,300]
```

I need to find the max index of each values which is divisible by 100.

Output should be like: `4,10,15`

My Code:

```
a = [77,98,99,100,101,102,198,199,200,200,278,299,300,300,300]
idx = 1
for i in (a):
    if i%100 == 0:
        print idx
    idx = idx+1
```

Output of above code:

```
4
9
10
13
14
15
```

Comment: all those who are saying that indexes should start at 0, guys that implementation is not correct anyway, even if he starts from 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case people are curious, I benchmarked the dict comprehension technique against the backward iteration technique. Dict comprehension is about twice the speed. Changing to `OrderedDict` resulted in MASSIVE slowdown. About 15x slower than the dict comprehension.

```
def test1():
    a = [77,98,99,100,101,102,198,199,200,200,278,299,300,300,300]
    max_index = {}
    for i, item in enumerate(a[::-1]):
        if item not in max_index:
            max_index[item] = len(a) - (i + 1)
    return max_index

def test2():
    a = [77,98,99,100,101,102,198,199,200,200,278,299,300,300,300]
    return {item: index for index, item in enumerate(a, 1)}

def test3():
    a = [77,98,99,100,101,102,198,199,200,200,278,299,300,300,300]
    OrderedDict((item, index) for index, item in enumerate(a, 1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test1()", setup="from __main__ import test1"))
    print(timeit.timeit("test2()", setup="from __main__ import test2"))
    print(timeit.timeit("test3()", setup="from __main__ import test3; from collections import OrderedDict"))

3.40622282028
1.97545695305
26.347012043
```

Comment: A normal loop is fine, old values will be replaced automatically.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That's pretty fair. I wanted to minimize writes for performance reasons, but not sure that actually works over minimizing the `in` checks.

Comment: Thanks Slater for detailed information and solution. Kudos!!

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple dict-comprehension or [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with divisible items as the keys, old values will be replaced by newest values automatically.

```
>>> {item: index for index, item in enumerate(lst, 1) if not item % 100}.values()
dict_values([4, 10, 15])

# if order matters
>>> from collections import OrderedDict    
>>> OrderedDict((item, index) for index, item in enumerate(lst, 1) if not item % 100).values()
odict_values([4, 10, 15])
```

Another way will be to loop over reversed list and use a `set` to keep track of items seen so far(`lst[::-1]` may be slightly faster than `reversed(lst)` for tiny lists).

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [len(lst) - index for index, item in enumerate(reversed(lst))
        if not item % 100 and item not in seen and not seen.add(item)][::-1]
[4, 10, 15]
```

You can see the sort-of equivalent code of the above [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347744/846892).

Comment: I wonder if the overhead of an `OrderedDict` is worth it vs sorting the values of a regular dict.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Just checked, looks like it's not unless there's something super specific in this use case that requires it.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `itertools.groupby` since your data is sorted:

```
>>> a = [77,98,99,100,101,102,198,199,200,200,278,299,300,300,300]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g)[-1][0] for k,g in groupby(enumerate(a), lambda t: (t[1] % 100, t[1])) if k[0] == 0]
[3, 9, 14]
```

Although this is a little cryptic.

Here's a complicated approach using only a list-iterator and accumulating into a list:

```
>>> run, prev, idx = False, None, []
>>> for i, e in enumerate(a):
...     if not (e % 100 == 0):
...         if not run:
...             prev = e
...             continue
...         idx.append(i - 1)
...         run = False
...     else:
...         if prev != e and run:
...             idx.append(i - 1)
...         run = True
...     prev = e
...
>>> if run:
...     idx.append(i)
...
>>> idx
[3, 9, 14]
```

I think this is best dealt with a dictionary approach like @AshwiniChaudhary It is more straightforward, and much faster:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("{item: index for index, item in enumerate(a, 1)}", "from __main__ import a")
1.842843743012054
>>> timeit.timeit("[list(g)[-1][0] for k,g in groupby(enumerate(a), lambda t: (t[1] % 100, t[1])) if k[0] == 0]", "from __main__ import a, groupby")
8.479677081981208
```

The `groupby` approach is pretty slow, note, the complicated approach is faster, and not far-off form the dict-comprehension approach:

```
>>> def complicated(a):
...     run, prev, idx = False, None, []
...     for i, e in enumerate(a):
...         if not (e % 100 == 0):
...             if not run:
...                 prev = e
...                 continue
...             idx.append(i - 1)
...             run = False
...         else:
...             if prev != e and run:
...                 idx.append(i - 1)
...             run = True
...         prev = e
...     if run:
...         idx.append(i)
...     return idx
...
>>> timeit.timeit("complicated(a)", "from __main__ import a, complicated")
2.6667005629860796
```

#### Edit

Note, the performance difference narrows if we call `list` on the dict-comprehension `.values()`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("list({item: index for index, item in enumerate(a, 1)}.values())", "from __main__ import a")
2.3839886570058297
>>> timeit.timeit("complicated(a)", "from __main__ import a, complicated")
2.708565960987471
```

Comment: You can make it slightly faster by caching `idx.append` in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

it seemed like a good idea at the start, got a bit twisty, had to patch a couple of cases...

```
a = [0,77,98,99,100,101,102,198,199,200,200,278,299,300,300,300, 459, 700,700]

bz = [*zip(*((i, d//100) for i, d in enumerate(a) if d%100 == 0 and d != 0))]
[a for a, b, c in zip(*bz, bz[1][1:]) if c-b != 0] + [bz[0][-1]]    

Out[78]: [4, 10, 15, 18]
```

enumerate, zip to create `bz` which mates 100's numerator(s) with indices

```
bz = [*zip(*((i, d//100) for i, d in enumerate(a) if d%100 == 0 and d != 0))]
print(*bz, sep='\n')
(4, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18)
(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7)
```

then zip again, `zip(*bz, bz[1][1:])` lagging the numerator tuple to allow the lagged difference to give a selection logic `if c-b != 0`for the last index of each run but the last

add the last 100's match because its always the end of the last run `+ [bz[0][-1]]`